# Browser downloading as .php file extension

Tags: settings, downloading, file-management, asus-zenfone-2

This morning I tried to download a number of mp3's from a lecture series (freely and legally available online) but when I searched for them from my media player app I discovered they were all titled "direct_download(x).php" instead of the normal "file name_number.mp3" and required manually editing the file extension back to .mp3 to function properly. It is specific to the site and the stock browser - switching to chrome or downloading .mp3's from a different (again, free and legal) site works normally.

Is this due to a change in the website? In the browser? Is there some way to fix this?

Technical info:
Asus ZenFone 2 4gb ram, 64gb memory (stock, unlocked and unrooted)
Android 5.0
Using default ASUS browser (because chrome doesn't allow you to set your download folder on MicroSD)

Comment: It's possible that the server generates the mp3 through a php script and send some meta data telling the browser the actual file name. The app, however,  might ignore that information and store the file as a plain php file.

Comment: @GiantTree neat. Is there a way to get it to recognize the meta data? It's all there (the mp3 player reads the song name correctly), but the file is misnamed.

Comment: Either tell the dev of the app to fix his app or use another browser to download your mp3s and move them wherever you want them.

Comment: @GiantTree Thanks - I've emailed the support team at ASUS and I'll update this question with their response.

Comment: @GiantTree Apparently this is an ongoing problem with the ASUS browser - they're working on a fix... They suggested using Chrome, but the whole reason I'm using the browser is that Chrome doesn't obey the OS download folder settings - I want it to save to the MicroSD instead of internal storage, and I can't make Chrome do that.